# Loop gone wrong somewhere

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, loops

I am trying to make a loop to find the first 10 valid numbers from the maths included in the script, but the problem is that I cannot get the loop to work correctly.

```
public class TestLoops{

 public static void main(String []args){
    int[] intArray = new int[6];
    String nextString;
    int count = 0;
    int nextnum;
    String s = "000000";
         int strLength = s.length();
          if(strLength != 6) {
   System.out.println("Not a valid length");
} else {

    do {
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
    nextString = s;
  intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(nextString.charAt(i)));
}
   int pos1 = intArray[5];
   int pos2 = intArray[4]*10;
   int pos3 = intArray[3]*100;
   int pos4 = intArray[2]*1000;
   int pos5 = intArray[1]*10000;
   nextnum = pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + 1;
   nextString = String.format("%06d", nextnum);


int d7 = ((4*intArray[0])+(10*intArray[1])+(9*intArray[2])+(2*intArray[3])+intArray[4]+(7*intArray[5])) % 11;
int d8 = ((7*intArray[0])+(8*intArray[1])+(7*intArray[2])+(intArray[3])+9*intArray[4]+(6*intArray[5])) % 11;
int d9 = ((9*intArray[0])+(intArray[1])+(7*intArray[2])+(8*intArray[3])+7*intArray[4]+(7*intArray[5])) % 11;
int d10 = ((intArray[0])+(2*intArray[1])+(9*intArray[2])+(10*intArray[3])+4*intArray[4]+(intArray[5])) % 11;


if (d7==10) { break;  }
else if (d8==10) { break; }
else if (d9==10) { break;  }
else if (d10==10) { break; }
else {
System.out.println("" + nextString + d7 + d8 + d9 + d10);
         count++;
}
    }
         while ( count < 10);{


}}
```

For reference the first three valid numbers are:
000000
000001
000002

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the problem? Is there an exception? What line throws it? Is the output wrong? What's the output and what's the intended output?

Comment: The problem is that the output shows: 0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000
0000010000, the intended output is the valid numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line 'nextString = s;'. Initialize the 'nextString = s' before the do-while loop. After the first iteration, nextString value will be updated. Currently it is set to '000000' for every loop iteration.

Comment: Thanks! I think the count may also be in the wrong place, as it only shows 3 values every time?

Comment: Do you want to see the first 10 values? I did not understand the purpose of d7,d8,d9,d10 variables. Could you please explain?